# Typescript class property required during runtime

Tags: typescript, rest, validation, metadata

is it possible to find out if a class property is declared required in Typescript during runtime?

```
export class A {
  public readonly ab?: number;
  public readonly ac?: number;
  public readonly ad: number;
  public readonly ae: number;
}
```

Is it possible to use emitDecoratorMetadata or experimentalDecorators to tell that ad and ae are required?

I'm asking because I'm writing a REST API and the object of A is automatically generated and I would like to validate if ad and ae are actually set when the request POST data is coming in.

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the type checking is about compile time, there are no type checks at run time. If you want to be sure that an received object is valid, you should check it manually or use an library, that will somehow validate the server response.

I can suggest [class-validator](https://github.com/typestack/class-validator) that supports class validation using decorators as well as plain object validation. To use the class validation, an object should be transformed into the class instance using `new Class()` syntax, see [Validating plain objects](https://github.com/typestack/class-validator#validating-plain-objects) section for more details.

Comment: was hoping that the experimental reflection with emitDecorator and experimentalDecorators would allow for that

Comment: @Thor_Bux Actually, the parsing logic might be implemented inside the http library that has used, but the implementation depends on the library. In general you receive an plain js object from the http call, which should be validated by you somehow.

Comment: Yes and I would like to base the validation on typescript type information that I define in the class. Otherwise I have the information in the class and inside my validation code. If the validation code could utilise ts metadata then it should know which property is required.

Comment: @Thor_Bux I've added reference to class-validator library to the answer, it supports class decorators validation as well. I hope it helps you.

Comment: That looks promising I'm going to have a deeper look

Comment: Thanks, does do what I wanted.